# Foreach List of variables from Array with a Variable Function returns Undefined offset: Error

Tags: php, function, undefined

Update:
If I remove`$1` from line 67 and 68 all Undefiened offset 2 errors are gone

Just one Undefined offset 1 error and that is the var without the x returns as "custom"

```
<?php list($w, $h, $1) = OX_Tools::explode_format($sformat); // Line 67?>
    <option<?php echo ($adformat == $sformat ? ' selected="selected"' : ''); ?> value="<?php echo $sformat; ?>"> <?php printf($formats['formats'][$sformat], $w, $h, $1); ?></option>

// Changed to This

<?php list($w, $h) = OX_Tools::explode_format($sformat); // Line 67?>
    <option<?php echo ($adformat == $sformat ? ' selected="selected"' : ''); ?> value="<?php echo $sformat; ?>"> <?php printf($formats['formats'][$sformat], $w, $h); ?></option>
```

Need some help with this one 
I get the Undefined offset:  1 notice when the value is a word "custom" 
I get the Undefined offset:  2 when the value is a number separated by an x performed by function `OX_Tools::explode_format`

I have read dozens of posts on this site and others and have tried several of the solutions with no luck in my situation. At this point not sure what else to try. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank You

results of `$sformat` after `explode_format` are

728x90
468x60

160x600
120x600

300x250
125x125

custom

results of `$sformats`

```
print_r($sformats);
Array
(
    [0] => 728x90
    [1] => 468x60
)
Array
(
    [0] => 728x90
    [1] => 468x60
)
Array
(
    [0] => 160x600
    [1] => 120x600
)
Array
(
    [0] => 160x600
    [1] => 120x600
)
Array
(
    [0] => 300x250
    [1] => 125x125
)

Array
(
    [0] => 300x250
    [1] => 125x125
)
Array
(
    [0] => custom
)
```

results of `$formats`

```
print_r($formats);
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [all] => Array
                (
                    [horizontal] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 728x90
                            [1] => 468x60
                        )

                    [vertical] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 160x600
                            [1] => 120x600
                        )

                    [square] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 300x250
                            [1] => 125x125
                        )

                    [custom] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => custom
                        )

                )

        )

    [types] => Array
        (
            [text] => Text ads
            [image] => Image ads
            [ref_text] => Text referrals
            [ref_image] => Image referrals
            [textimage] => Text and image ads
            [link] => Ad links
            [video] => Video ads
            [all] => All ad types
        )

    [sections] => Array
        (
            [horizontal] => Horizontal
            [vertical] => Vertical
            [square] => Square
            [other] => Other ad formats
            [custom] => Custom width and height
        )

    [formats] => Array
        (
            [728x90] => %1$s x %2$s Leaderboard
            [468x60] => %1$s x %2$s Banner
            [160x600] => %1$s x %2$s Wide Skyscraper
            [120x600] => %1$s x %2$s Skyscraper
            [300x250] => %1$s x %2$s Medium Rectangle
            [125x125] => %1$s x %2$s Button
            [custom] => Custom width and height
        )

)
```

The error is on line 67 here is the code

```
<?php foreach ($sformats as $sformat) : ?>
<?php list($w, $h, $l) = OX_Tools::explode_format($sformat); //Line 67?> 
            <option<?php echo ($adformat == $sformat ? ' selected="selected"' : ''); ?> value="<?php echo $sformat; ?>"> <?php printf($formats['formats'][$sformat], $w, $h, $l); ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Here is the Function `OX_Tools::explode_format`

```
<?php
static function explode_format($format)
{
    $vars = preg_split("/[x#]+/", $format);
    return $vars;
}
?>
```

Comment: The code has no sense for me. You need to attach a clear verifiable example to try to reproduce the problem. For example, you don't attach the code related to `$formats['formats'][$sformat]` and I think the undefined offset error is here...

Comment: So I Added indices to `return $vars[0];` in the function and the error went away however the output of the html is not correct this was the point of my question that someone doesn’t like I was not sure if it was the function or line 67 I needed to edit.

html result
`<option value="728x90"> 7 x 2 Leaderboard</option>`
`<option value="468x60"> 4 x 6 Banner</option>`
should be
`<option value="728x90"> 728 x 90 Leaderboard</option>`
`<option value="468x60"> 468 x 60 Banner</option>`
 

Will look at line 68 and see if i can make html output correct or go back and continue to look at 67

Comment: Why you need preg_split? Is not enough `explode("x", $var)`?

Comment: not all var's have x in this example one var's is "custom" I think the original author did it this way to seperate `$w` and `$h` to display in options `printf($formats['formats'][$sformat], $w, $h);` I added results of `$formats` to original post so all data used in code sample can be viewed. @MarcosPérezGude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is the solution I came up with. Sorry some of you did not like the question. Perhaps because I did not provide an executable example or similar questions have been asked in the past None that where exactly like mine.

I have found so many solutions to problems here on Stack and realized I have not been giving back therefore I plan to spend more time on the site and will try to contribute.

Enough of that! While I was waiting to see if someone would just say you missed this `something` I was looking at the `$1` variable in the list and trying to figure out why! There are 38 files in this project not including javascript and language files it must have been there for something that was removed from a previous author.

When I removed `$1` from `list($w, $h, $l)` in lines 67 and 68 all but one errors where gone and code executed just as it was intended.

As I stated in the update this left me with just one Undefined offset error and had to be related to the variable not matching what the `preg_split()` function could match.

What I tried was `if $sformat != ‘custom’`  it would use the `preg_split()` and that cleared all errors. I tested the rest of the plugin and had no errors. Great! Since users can create their own formats naming then any thing they want matching `custom` was no good. I used `preg_match()` function to eliminate any non conforming variables from being split.

Here is the original lines 67

```
<?php list($w, $h, $l) = OX_Tools::explode_format($sformat); ?>
```

I changed it to

```
<?php if (!preg_match("/[0-9]x[0-9]/", $sformat)) {$sformat = $sformat;}else{list($w, $h) = OX_Tools::explode_format($sformat); } ?>
```

If you see a problem with my solution please comment

Thank you @Marcos Pérez Gude for commenting however if it would have been `explode("x", $var)` that easy I wouldn’t have asked the question people didn’t like and would not have been inspired to participate in the Stackoverflow community more.

Live every day like it’s your last…. One day it will be!